# Laravel Inertia controller per page or per model?

Tags: laravel-8, inertiajs

I am little confused by how controllers in Laravel Inertia should be used.  On the inertia documentation it says "With Inertia, each page in your application has its own controller".  However, on most tutorials it seems to be using controllers on the model in the normal way.  What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I see there is already a project built with laravel8 and inertiajs which is already answering your questions https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/tree/master/app/Http/Controllers